# Is it possible to have placeholders in kong plugin k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "kong-ingress"
    konghq.com/strip-path: "true"
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: test
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /path/test/{id1}/{id2}/
```

I am wondering if is possible to have a path set like this in the plugin /path/test/{id1}/{id2}/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for path was using regex

**/path/test/[a-fA-F0-9]+/[a-fA-F0-9]+/**